# Undo git reset --mixed origin/master

Tags: xcode, git

I call `git reset --mixed origin/master` but I want to go back to my last commit.

I try `git reset --mixed 'HEAD@{11}'` but it doesn't work.

**Console with** `git reflog` :

```
624378f (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~6
f8b5338 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD~2
df2eb34 HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
c224dd7 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD~7
54b3efd (master) HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD@{6}
44d1989 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD@{4}
adccd20 HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to HEAD@{5}
44d1989 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD@{2}
54b3efd (master) HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to HEAD@{2}
24d6bcb HEAD@{9}: commit: This is a new commit for what I originally planned to be amended
44d1989 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{10}: pull --rebase origin master: checkout 44d1989fd6beda2b2ccfb91aaae8ffce45ab7ecb
54b3efd (master) HEAD@{11}: commit: Test de tout re commit
```

How to return to commit : "Test de tout re commit" ?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're using the `--mixed` flag?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do that :

```
git checkout 54b3efd -- <file>
```